# How do I communicate with Arduino Mega 2560 r3?

Tags: 13.04, drivers, arduino

I recently purchased Arduino Mega, and I'm tring it to make it communicate with Ubuntu 13.04 64bit, without success.

At arduino IDE the option **Tools → Serial Port** is grayed out.

Is there any driver I need to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this link: http://www.ladyada.net/learn/arduino/lesson0-lin.html

If it does not work, you can use:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre avr-libc gcc-avr
```

I have an Arduino UNO and went through the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed the guide but it stuck on the step that it says to type on terminal ls /dev/ttyUSB*. No such file or direcctory. I also tried the other options described at the guide, with no luck..

Comment: Tried it? 

sudo apt-get install gcc-avr avr-libc

Comment: http://imageshack.us/f/9/swma.png/

This is what i get

Comment: I fixed it.. Thanks..
I downloaded the 1.0.3 IDE version from ubuntu software center thats why it didnt worked. It worked great with 1.0.5!!

Comment: It is true! I also had installed version 1.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Hey i found a solution to my problem

its simple download the arduino 1.0.5 from the website.

make sure you download java from java.com

the problem is in the |dailout| make sure you are registered in the it and everything will work just fine.

Comment: Could you give more details? How exactly I do that? Edit your question and be more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

If had the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04 and an Arduino Mega 2560 R3 where no /dev/ttyACM* device was created.

Output of dmesg was

```
usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0042
usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 854303432383514012A0
usb 3-2: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 1024 microframes, ep desc says 2040 microframes
```

It turns out, the module cdc_acm which creates the device was not loaded so a simple

> sudo modprobe cdc_acm

fixed the issue, port was selectable in Arduino IDE and worked flawlessly.

Dmesg then showed additionally:

```
cdc_acm 3-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
```